# question about cauchy sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For which values of $\lambda$ is the sequence $f_n : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f_n(x) = 2^{- \lambda n x } $ when $x \in [0,2^{-n}]$ and $0$ otherwise, Cauchy sequence in $L^7([0,1])$??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, $\lambda$ must be positive, otherwise the sequence does not even converge.

The distance between two terms $f_n$ and $f_{n+k}$ is given by:

$$
\| f_n - f_{n+k} \|_7 = \| g_{(n, n+k)}\|_7
$$

where $g$ is given by

$$
g_{(n, n+k)}(x) =  \begin{cases}
2^{-n\lambda x} - 2^{-(n+k)\lambda x}\text{ for $x\in[0,2^{-n-k}]$}\\
f_n(x) = 2^{-n\lambda x}\text{ for $x\in[2^{-n-k}, 2^{-n}]$}\\
0 \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

an you can see that you have $0 ≤ g_{(n, n+k)} ≤ f_n$ if $\lambda > 0$. So all the $f_{n+k}$ are contained in a ball centered at $f_n$, with radius $\|f_n\|_7$, which tends to $0$ when $n\to\infty$.